# How to create a binary to deploy Python

Tags: python, deployment, centos, package

I work in a highly compliant environment, and need a very specific **Python** version (**3.7.6**) to be deployed on some production servers running **CentOS 7**. Deploying compiling the source code directly on the machine is a no-go, and 3.7.* doesn't appear to be in any of the allowed repository. 
I have development servers which are supposed to be a clone of the production one, both from hardware, software and most of the configuration perspective. Is it possible to produce a **binary installer** (so, no, less or included dependencies) that I can deploy, like an **RPM**, and if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: You can not compile the Cpython source code on the server?